# preBlur event is not captured in Selenium

Tags: selenium

In the following code, preBlur event is not getting fired in Selenium Webdriver.

```
var monikerOldValue = '';
this.editor.on( 'open', function ( e, type ) {
    monikerOldValue = self.editor.get().moniker;
}).on( 'preBlur', function ( e ) {
    self.isDirty = self.editor.get().moniker !== monikerOldValue;
});
```

I am using [jQuery editor](https://editor.datatables.net/) for inline editing.

Using selenium chrome WebDriver to run automation test case.

Any fix for that?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it temporarily by using `blur` event.